# Is it possible to get return values selectively on single-value contexts in Go?

Tags: go, return-value

A simple example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func hereTakeTwo() (x, y int) {
    x = 0
    y = 1
    return
}

func gimmeOnePlease(x int){
    fmt.Println(x)
}

func main() {
    gimmeOnePlease(hereTakeTwo()) // fix me
}
```

Is it possible to pass only first returned value from `hereTakeTwo()` **without** using an explicit `_` assignment? Example of what I would like to avoid:

```
func main() {
    okJustOne, _ := hereTakeTwo()
    gimmeOnePlease(okJustOne)
}
```

What I want is to make `gimmeOnePlease` function able to receive an undefined number of arguments but take only first one **OR** a way to call `hereTakeTwo` function and get only first returned value without the necessity to use `_` assignments.

Or on a last resort (crazy idea) use some kind of adapter function, that takes N args and reurns only first one, and have something like:

```
func main() {
    gimmeOnePlease(adapter(hereTakeTwo()))
}
```

Why? I'm just testing the boundaries of the language and learning how flexible it can be to some purposes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you cannot do that apart from one special case [described](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls) in the Spec:

> As a special case, if the return values of a function or method `g` are equal in number and individually assignable to the parameters of another function or method `f`, then the call `f(g(parameters_of_g))` will invoke `f` after binding the return values of `g` to the parameters of `f` in order. The call of `f` must contain no parameters other than the call of `g`, and `g` must have at least one return value.

The best you can do besides the temporary variables (which are the best option) is this:

```
func first(a interface{}, _ ...interface{}) interface{} {
    return a
}

func main() {
    gimmeOnePlease(first(hereTakeTwo()).(int))
}
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/VXv-tsYjXt

Variadic version: http://play.golang.org/p/ulpdp3Hppj

Comment: Another possibility would be to use [variadic functions](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_types) if you know the type: http://play.golang.org/p/_CoKooBiyS

Comment: @Ainar-G Ok, so the adapter is possible! It would work even better with: func first(a int, _ ...interface{}) int